# adding text under a link icon

Tags: html, css

I have this link that i embedded into an icon and i wanted to add a description text underneath the icon itself.

**Example:** email icon and underneath it i would have "Email"

This is what i have currently for my link and i would like to add to it the title "Email"

```
<a title="Email"  class="icon-envelope" data-bind="attr: { 'href': 'mailto:' + Email() }"></a>
```

How could i use the combination of css and html to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the CSS for "icon-envelope"?  I assume its just a background image?

Comment: @Lowkase yes i am using twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I'm guessing you have entered a height for the anchor, if you change this to padding top, you can just add the text into your anchor and it will appear below the icon

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a title="Email" class="icon-envelope" data-bind="attr: { 'href': 'mailto:' + Email() }">Email</a>
```

CSS

```
.icon-envelope {
    display:block; 
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:110px 0 0 0;
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/GKC9e/

Comment: personally I avoid setting fixed widths and heights on textual elements to allow them to be more flexible (e.g. text content changes/localisation)

Comment: agreed, if there is a responsive requirement to the website then this solution is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

[Verbose] **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FCP9k/

### CSS

```
a[title] {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/100'); /* Default image */
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
a[title="Email"] {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200'); /* Email icon */
}
a[title="SomethingElse"] {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/300'); /* A different icon */
}

a[title]:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: personally I avoid setting fixed widths and heights on textual elements to allow them to be more flexible (e.g. text content changes/localisation)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a title="Email"  class="icon-envelope" data-bind="attr: { 'href': 'mailto:' + Email() }">Email</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-envelope {
    padding-top:100px; /*height of bg image*/
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<a href="foo">
    <img src="bar" alt="">
    <br>
    Email
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="foo">
    <img src="bar" alt="">
    Email
</a>
```

with

```
a img { display: block; }
```

Comment: i already have the image being displayed from my css via icon-envelope class so i don't have an image tag.

Comment: It's a content image, you should have an img tag.